# EdgeForm with Graphics

Tags: graphics

I want my figure to have an edge and I am playing around with EdgeForm[Thick], putting it in different places. My figure is:

```
listb = {{{0, 0}, {0, -0.1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 0.1}}};
Rasterize[
Graphics[{Arrowheads[Norm@#2/5], Arrow[{#1, #1 + #2}]} & @@@ listb], 
RasterSize -> 1000]
```

What should I do to have an edge (actually four, making a square with the two arrows inside).

Thank you.

Comment: Try adding the option `Frame->True` to your `Graphics` expression.  You can turn off the tick marks with the additional option `FrameTicks->None`.  You can use the options `PlotRange` and/or `PlotRangePadding` to control the spacing between the frame and the contents.  BTW, `EdgeForm` is unrelated to what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly what you want:

```
listb = {{{0, 0}, {0, -0.1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 0.1}}};

gr = Graphics[{Arrowheads[Norm@#2/5], Arrow[{#1, #1 + #2}]} & @@@ listb];

Rasterize[Framed[gr, FrameMargins -> 0], ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

See all the options of [`Framed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Framed.html) for customization.